# PyCharm: Jupyter notebook is not rendered, and it is not run-able

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm Professional latest version.
jupyter package installed
When I create a new ipynb file, this is everything I have:

[image]

I cannot run the file. I cannot view the rendered HTML. I basically cannot do anything with the file.

Comment: "Text" file icon makes me think `*.ipynb` is associated with a wrong file type. Make sure `ipynb` is *not* present in **Settings | Editor | File Types | Text | File name patterns**.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating the file with `File > New > Jupyter Notebook`? Otherwise you can go to `File > File Properties > Associate with File Type...` and create a pattern there.